# Oracle SQL: CTE Query gives different results in TOAD, depending on how executed

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have what appears to be a rather straight-forward CTE query:

```
with cte1 as 
( 
    Select row_number () over (
         order by id1 desc
         )rn,
         T.*         
from   schema1.table1 T
)
select * from cte1
WHERE (rn < 11)  
ORDER BY rn, id1 desc
;
```

However, it gives different results when executed, using the "TOAD" database tool.

If I use the execute button ("play"), it gives what I think are the correct results, including a row I **inserted recently**.

If I use the "Execute as Script" button, it gives a different result, omitting the **recently inserted** row.

For security reasons, I've changed details such as schema name, table name, and column name.  Also, I can't provide the actual data used.

Is there a valid reason why one gets different results, depending on how the query is run?

To me, this is deeply troubling, and I would find it a "bug", not a "feature".

NOTE:  Per the accepted answer, the problem was in the (unshown) insert script [not committing the insert], *NOT* with the CTE code or with TOAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you `COMMIT` your data.

If you do not `COMMIT` then only the session where the the data was created can see the uncommitted data and other sessions, even those belonging to the same user, will never see that uncommitted data.

For example, the behaviour can be explained:

- if Toad keeps the session open and re-uses it for its "play" action then it will see uncommitted data that was created earlier in the session.
- However, if Toad spawns a new session for the same user when it uses the "Execute as Script" action then it will not see the uncommitted data.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem.  So the "bug" was that I didn't commit with the (unshown) insert script, and when I did, the problem went away.

Comment: @JosephDoggie The unexpected "feature" is that Toad uses different sessions for the two methods of execution (rather than reusing the same session). You can argue whether using different sessions is a bug or not but from the user's point-of-view then, as you found, when there is uncommitted data it can lead to different behaviour; not committing is not a bug and using different sessions probably has a valid reason but the behaviour does not meet the user's expectation (even if it can be explained).

Comment: In the context of what I was trying to do "not committing" was an omission on my part, like a bug.  Obviously, it would depend on context.